# MySQL. No directory, logging in with HOME=/

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.1 x32 - it is my home server. Recently I had MySQL 5.5 installed, but now I want to upgrade it to 5.7 using APT repository from MySQL official site, but now it cannot be started at all.
Installation finishes with

```
...
Setting up mysql-community-server (5.7.21-1ubuntu14.04) ...
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
..................................................................................................................................................................................
* MySQL Community Server 5.7.21 did not start. Please check logs for more details.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.14) ...
```

`sudo service mysql start` has the same result.

`/var/log/mysql/error.log` outputs nothing.

My first attempts to upgrade had another error, something like "Can't read directory of '/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)" right before "No directory, logging in with HOME=/". After some more attempts first error is gone, but this one still remains.

Do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No magic worked. Tried [installation from binaries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-installation.html), and it helped.